# Google Fusion queries: using wildcard for LOCATION parameter

Tags: sql, google-fusion-tables

I am querying a Google Fusion table as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM {mytableIDhere} WHERE col1 LIKE '%{mystringhere}%'
```

This shows all row data for entries containing `{mystringhere}` in column 1. Is it possible to use a `*` wildcard on the column field, so that the search applies to ANY column? I tried that, but I get a parse error when doing:

```
SELECT * FROM {mytableIDhere} WHERE * LIKE '%{mystringhere}%'
```

It seems that the location parameter cannot be open-ended. Is this correct? If so, is there a workaround?

EDIT: In terms of desired functionality, I am trying to create a global search of a table so that any rows containing the search query will be returned. The columns include e-mail addresses, ID numbers, commentary, and other values.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible with a fusiontable

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of trouble.